# Machine reaching out to Microsoft IP address using NBTstat command

Tags: ports, udp, siem

I have limited logs for this event but the IPS says its a NBTstat query outbound over UDP port 137 to a Microsoft owned IP address.

Should UDP 137 ever reach out externally?

This is about all the information I have as its very limited access to the client.